# Is the conversion of this English sentence into predicate logic correct

Tags: logic, proof-verification, predicate-logic

Hi I wanted to know if I have converted this sentence into predicate logic correctly.

This is the sentence

```
The child of a blue bird and yellow bird is blue
```

This is my formula

```
 ∀X•(blueBird(X) ∧ yellowBird(X)) ⇒ ∀Y•(childOf(Y,X) ∧ blue(Y))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the sentence is supposed to mean the child has two parents, where one parent is blue and the other is yellow, whereas your expression says the child has one parent that is both blue and yellow.

Comment: @DanSimon I read that as if X is a blue bird and X yellow bird, then for all Y. Y is the child of X and Y is blue

Comment: Yes and based on that reading, your sentence (or at least the left-hand side, the right side has another error :) ) is correct.  But my point was that the way it's written as "blue bird and yellow bird" leads me to believe they're talking about two different birds, not one multi-colored bird.  Otherwise it would probably say "the child of a blue and yellow bird".

Comment: @DanSimon oh right i get your point, thanks

Comment: Also, "then for all Y. Y is the child of X and Y is blue" is almost certainly not what you want.  This would mean that _everything_ is a child is $X$: you, me, the Earth, etc.  I think what you want to say is "for all Y, _if_ Y is a child of $X$ _then_ $Y$ is blue".

Comment: @DanSimon Thanks I get it now, I will change it to There exists a Y, where if Y is the child of X then Y is blue

Comment: No @user5647516  You want the universal, as Dan Simon indicated. You want to say, "*Anything* $Y$, *if* there exists a bird $X$ such that $Y$ is the child of $X$ and $X$ is blue and yellow, then $Y$ is blue."  (Although I *too* read the original sentence as discussing two different coloured parents, and suggest you instead talk about $X,Y,$ *and* $Z$).

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't. Your first order sentence says (or would say, if it had enough parentheses): for everything $x$ that is both a blue and a yellow bird, everything $y$ is a child of $x$ and is blue.

You mean
$$
\forall x\forall y[(blueBird(x)\land yellowBird(y))\to \forall z(childOf(z,x,y)\to blue(z))]
$$
using the same predicates you have, but making $childOf$ three-place, as it must be in this case.